# ActionScript 3 - Collision detection of objects in an array issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

I'm working on a small flash game and am currently trying to implement multiplayer for up to 4 players. While the collision detection for 1 player works perfectly, when more players are added **only the last player can collide** with other objects.

Using trace statements I discovered that calling the x and y coordinates of the problematic players from the main class **returns the initial x and y positions** and not the current coordinates (`trace(players[0].x + "/" + players[0].y);`), while calling them from within the player class (`trace(this.x + "/" + this.y);`) always gives the correct values.

The last player will always return the correct coordinates in both classes. Below is a skeleton of the main class.

```
public class main extends MovieClip {

    public var collisionObject: Array = new Array(14);
    public var players: Array = new Array();
    private var noOfPlayers = 2;

    public function main() {
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfPlayers; i++) {
            setupPlayer(i);
            stage.addChild(players[i]);
        }
        setupCollisionObject();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkForCollision);
    }

    private function setupCollisionObject() {
      /* Determines positions of and spawns objects */ 
    }

    private function setupPlayer(playerNo) {
        switch (playerNo) {
            case 3:
                players[3] = new player(1000, 576, 180, 104, 100, 102);
            case 2:
                players[2] = new player(24, 576, 0, 73, 74, 76);
            case 1:
                players[1] = new player(1000, 384, 180, 38, 37, 39);
            case 0:
                players[0] = new player(24, 384, 0, 87, 65, 68);
        }
    }

    public function checkForCollision(e: Event) {

        trace("x: "+players[0].x+" y: "+players[0].y);
        trace("x: "+players[1].x+" y: "+players[1].y);

        for (var i in players) {
            for (var j in collisionObject) {
                if (players[i].hitTestObject(collisionObject[j])) {
                    //damage player
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss of why this is happening.

Comment: We need more code than what is provided. Are you updating the coordinates of every player or just the coordinates of one player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `break;` in your switch-case in `setupPlayer()`, this results in all players but the last reinitialize during each call of `setupPlayers(i)`.

```
private function setupPlayer(playerNo) {
    switch (playerNo) {
        case 3:
            players[3] = new player(1000, 576, 180, 104, 100, 102);
            break;
        case 2:
            players[2] = new player(24, 576, 0, 73, 74, 76);
            break;
        case 1:
            players[1] = new player(1000, 384, 180, 38, 37, 39);
            break;
        case 0:
            players[0] = new player(24, 384, 0, 87, 65, 68);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer, thanks. Hilariously I had purposefully excluded them in the belief I was only running setupPlayer() once.